# Move to file position from magit-diff

Tags: magit

`diff-mode` allows to move (by <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>) or to apply hunk and to move (by <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-a</kbd>) to position of original source file where hunk is placed.

How can I do that in Magit Rev mode? On <kbd>RET</kbd> it opens buffer unrelated to file with corresponding content for file version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that <kbd>RET</kbd> *may or may not* visit the current file.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> tells us:

> <return> runs the command `magit-diff-visit-file` ...
>
> [...]
>
> If the diff shows changes in the worktree, the index, or HEAD,
>   then visit the actual file.  Otherwise, when the diff is about an
>   older commit or a range, then visit the appropriate blob.
>
> The optional FORCE-WORKTREE means to force visiting the worktree
>   version of the file.  **To do this interactively use the command
>   `magit-diff-visit-file-worktree` instead.**

You can use <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to call `magit-diff-visit-file-worktree`:

> From a diff, visit the corresponding file at the appropriate position.
>
> [...]
>
> The actual file in the worktree is visited. The positions in the
>   hunk headers get less useful the "older" the changes are, and
>   as a result, jumping to the appropriate position gets less
>   reliable.

Jumping to the current file is, more often than not, what I *want* to
do, and so I use the following to swap the meaning of <kbd>RET</kbd>
and <kbd>C-RET</kbd>.

```el
(with-eval-after-load "magit-diff"
  ;; Swap the meanings of RET and C-RET on diff hunks.
  ;; Note that the default RET bindings are [remap magit-visit-thing]
  ;; in the original keymaps, but I am only concerned with RET here.
  ;; Note also that in a terminal, C-RET sends C-j.
  ;; Using the same key formats here as magit-diff.el
  (define-key magit-file-section-map [return] 'magit-diff-visit-file-worktree)
  (define-key magit-file-section-map [C-return] 'magit-diff-visit-file)
  (define-key magit-file-section-map (kbd "C-j") 'magit-diff-visit-file)
  (define-key magit-hunk-section-map [return] 'magit-diff-visit-file-worktree)
  (define-key magit-hunk-section-map [C-return] 'magit-diff-visit-file)
  (define-key magit-hunk-section-map (kbd "C-j") 'magit-diff-visit-file))
```